# Compare three files using two columns and print unique entries in each file using awk/sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, overlap

I have three files with following format:

```
$ cat a.bed 
chr1    6   6   aa
chr1    8   8   bb
chr2    22  22  aa
chr3    24  24  bb

$ cat b.bed 
chr1    12  12  cc
chr1    6   6   dd
chr5    14  14  cc

$ cat c.bed 
chr1    8   8   ss
chr4    11  11  dd
chr1    6   6   aa
```

I want  to compare these files using first two columns and print information for each row whether it is present in one file or multiple files, like:

```
chr1    6   6   aa  3   a.bed,b.bed,c.bed
chr1    8   8   bb  2   a.bed,c.bed
chr2    22  22  aa  1   a.bed
chr3    24  24  bb  1   a.bed
chr1    12  12  cc  1   b.bed
chr5    14  14  cc  1   b.bed
chr4    11  11  dd  1   c.bed
```

where 5th column gives number of of files it is present in and 6th column gives name of the files.

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many people don't like that.

Comment: How do you determine the 4th column aa, bb, ... in your desired output?   They look different across input files.

Comment: @tshiono, the question says "*compare these files using first two columns*". The desired output only contains two entries that match multiple files, and the 4th column shown is from the first file in each of them. I would suggest that "first match wins".

Comment: @John1024 sorry for posting it without showing what I tried. Actually the code I wrote could do it for two files. i couldn't understand how to approach it for more than two files, that is why I did not put it up. I will take care of it next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{a[$1,$2]=(($1,$2) in a?a[$1,$2]",":$0 OFS)FILENAME}
   END{for(k in a) print a[k]}' {a,b,c}.bed
```

results won't be in the same order though.

**Explanation**

> `x=c?a:b` is the ternary operator, sets x to a or b based on value of c (similar to if-then-else).  Here we assign the value of map for key `($1,$2)` either by appending `FILENAME` (if already exists) or setting to the current line (again by appending `FILENAME`).  In the `END` block, just iterates over this map, and prints the values.

Comment: Close: put `{...}` around the `print a[k]` :-)

Comment: @karakfa Thanks for the solution, it works fine just that there is an extra filename in last but one line.  I tried resolving it, but no luck. Could you please suggest a change?

Comment: can't see why it's happening.  Are you sure ($1,$2) are the only field you need to match?

Comment: It worked, the  problem was in the input files. Thanks! Could you explain it a bit I am not able to get the first part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these four lines of gawk (doesn't appear to work in awk):

```
gawk '{print $0, FILENAME}' a.bed > abc.bed
gawk '{print $0, FILENAME}' b.bed >> abc.bed
gawk '{print $0, FILENAME}' c.bed >> abc.bed
gawk '{f = $5;k=$1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4;if(k in a){a[k] = a[k] "," f}else{a[k] = f};c[k]++};END{for(k in a){print k, c[k], a[k]}}' abc.bed
```

Single char variables for brevity:
f - file name,
k - key, i.e. the data,
a - an array of keys,
c - an array of key counts.

Er, if I am reading it right, your input and output data samples don't match, e.g. there are only 2 'chr1    6   6   aa' not 3.